# Потеря точности Bigdecimal

Tags: java, swing, bigdecimal

Создается переменная `BigDecimal bet = new BigDecimal(0.00000010)` и передается на сервер и он возвращает значение отличное от ожидаемого.
Не понятно почему так.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

При использовании конструктора, принимающего на вход `double`, возникает неприятная особенность, отмеченная в документации.

> Поскольку вещественное число при переводе в двоичную форму
>   представляется, как правило, бесконечной двоичной дробью, то при
>   создании объекта, например, `BigDecimal(0.1)`, мантисса, хранящаяся в
>   объекте, окажется очень большой. ([ссылка на статью](http://www.realcoding.net/teach/java/Glava4/Index5.htm))

Поэтому число будет сохранено неточно. В связи с этим лучше используйте конструктор, принимающий на вход строку:

```
Bigdecimal bet = new Bigdecimal("0.00000010");
```